# Using overpass turbo to download all windfarms on admin level 6 in germany

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, overpass-api

I managed to write a query which extracts all windfarms:

```
[out:json][timeout:150];
(
{{geocodeArea:"Lüneburg"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Nienburg/Weser"}}; 
{{geocodeArea:"Uslar"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Dassel"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Einbeck"}}; 
{{geocodeArea:"Northeim"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Moringen"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Hardegsen"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Bad Gandersheim"}}; 
{{geocodeArea:"Oldenburg"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Dötlingen"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Ganderkesee"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Großenkneten"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Hatten"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Hude"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Wardenburg"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Wildeshausen"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Osnabrück"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Osterholz"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Peine"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Rotenburg (Wümme)"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Salzgitter"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Schaumburg"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Stade"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Uelzen"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Vechta"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Verden"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Brake"}}; 
{{geocodeArea:"Butjadingen"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Wilhelmshaven"}}; 
{{geocodeArea:"Wittmund"}}; 
{{geocodeArea:"Wolfenbüttel"}};
{{geocodeArea:"Wolfsburg"}};
)->.myArea;

node["generator:source"="wind"](area.myArea);
out meta;
```

The Problem is, that some of the administrative regions have the sam e Name as a City in this Region. Unfortunately overpass takes the name of the city instead of the region, so that only the wind farms in the City are selected.

Is there a way I can make clear, that I am searching for the Region and not for a single City?

Comment: Easier method, yet with some gaps in the data: get the excel from https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Sachgebiete/ElektrizitaetundGas/Unternehmen_Institutionen/ErneuerbareEnergien/ZahlenDatenInformationen/EEG_Registerdaten/EEG_Registerdaten_node.html, save it as csv and import it.

Comment: Thank you, I am beware of this method, but I am trying it to do it with overpass :)

Comment: Since there are not that many wind turbines, you could limit the data types you want to receive to "point" and then do the whole state? For Mecklenburg it worked.